# Keycloak redirects to the keycloak URI instead of redirect_uri provided

Tags: nginx, keycloak

We are trying to authenticate an application using keycloak. Both the applications are hosted behind nginx and the nginx configuration seems fine (shown below)

The issue we are having is that the redirect_url we specify is something like https://website.com/myapplication/auth but keycloak redirects to its own domain at https://auth.website.com/myapplication/auth

We tried to debug this issue but cannot figure out what could be the issue. any pointers would be appreciated.

nginx configuration

```
server{
    listen 443;
    server_name auth.website.com;
    ... certificates

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_pass              http://localhost:8080;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you redirect to auth? `redirect_uri` is expected to be the uri to redirect once the log in process gets done. Also you miss many info here, the adapter being used, your application configuration...

Comment: *https://website.com/myapplication/auth* is the redirect_uri we provide. We tried with nodejs adapter, the spring boot adapter and manually as well. 
The issue is that redirect_uri doesnt redirect to *website.com* but to *auth.website.com* 
I'll add one of the configs to the question in a while.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed by changing the nginx configuration to the following

```
server{
    listen 443;
    server_name auth.website.com;
    ... certificates

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;

        proxy_buffer_size 64k;
        proxy_buffers 8 64k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9090;
    }
}
```